# VirtualBox guest crashes with `memory cannot be written` notice

Tags: virtualbox, crash

I have a `Windows 7 64bit guest` on a `Windows 7 64bits host` *VirtualBox 5.0.26.*

In undetermined times/circumstances, the VirtualBox guest crashes with:

[image: crash notice]

### Any idea how the above can be resolved?

*Edit 1:* this happens only in VirtualBox, never on the host.

Comment: Have you considered using the current version of VBox?

Comment: Actually, @Ramhound, I did upgrade to `Version 5.1.2 r108956,` but am still getting these crashes.

Comment: Has VirtualBox ever work on the system?

Comment: It's working all the time, @Ramhound. It just crashes in undetermined times/circumstances (say, 5-10 times a month).

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have similar with version 5.2 and 6

Comment: The current Version 5.2.24 r128163 (Qt5.6.2) I use does not have this problem, but then - my current machine has 16GB memory (as opposed to the 8GB my then machine had).