# VBox: "memory could not be written" crash when enumerating USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox

I have a similar question to [this (unsolved) one](https://superuser.com/q/1110804), but mine has a big difference. I *exactly* know when the following error appears:

> The instruction at 0x00000000 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be written.

**It happens every time I right-click on the USB icon** (inside the VM) to enumerate the USB device available.

I updated both Host and Guest Additions to the latest version:

- Host: 5.2.8 under Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- G.A.: 5.2.8 under Debian 4.6.1-1

It seems there are no differences about what devices are connected.

Comment: This isn't the VirtualBox bug report form – you're looking for https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker.

Comment: Well, I thought is was my fault and someone else had a suggestion. Thank you for your kind comment.

Comment: Do you have the Virtualbox extension pack?

Comment: If it crashes, then it's a bug in the program. Even _if_ you're doing something wrong, the program is supposed to handle it and e.g. show an error message – not crash. So yes, submit a bug report.